# Changing a date value in pandas based on condition and converting to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column that looks like a date but is actually an Object (`type 'O'`). Some of the values in that column have a value of `9999-12-31 00:00:00.000`. They are in a sense an indicator that a row is valid 'indefinitely'.

`pd.to_datetime()` fails on these values and gives a "date out of range" error. I tried to write a function that converts the values to a string, and then checks the first character to see if it's 9, but that's not working either.

Just so you believe that I have tried something, these are the two functions I have tried:

```
def change_to_datetime(df, colname):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        string = str(row[12])
        if string[0] == '9':
            row[12] = '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
        row[12] = pd.to_datetime(row[12])
    return df
```

And:

```
def change_to_datetime2(df, colname):
    mask = str(df.colname)[0] == '9'
    df.loc[mask, colname] = '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    df[colname] = pd.to_datetime(df[colname])
    return df
```

I have also read other similar questions here, but they didn't help me. I'm quite a novice in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `9999` is the only issue, you can use `errors='coerce'` to convert invalid input in to `NaT` null values.  You can then fill those in with `'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'`

Use this and assign it to whatever column you'd like

```
filler = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
pd.to_datetime(df[colname], errors='coerce').fillna(filler)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `df.replace()` and replace the string `'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'`?

`df.replace(to_replace='9999-12-31 00:00:00.000', value='2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', inplace = True)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html